# For which a the matrix is positive-definite

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&2\\ 2&a+1\end{pmatrix}$
And I want to know for which a the matrix is positive-definite.
So our requirement is $det(A)\ge0$
$(a*(a+1))-4\ge0$
$a^2+a-4\ge0$
I understand that in the points $\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2},\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}$ the function are equal to zero.
Is it true to say that because the function is equal to zero in the points so $ ∀a>\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2},\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}$
$a^2+a-4\ge0$?

Comment: "So our requirement is $\det(A) \geq 0$". Are you sure this is correct? If $\det(A) = 0$, then it's possible that one of the eigenvalues is negative and the other is zero. That wouldn't be a positive definite matrix. Similarly, $\det(A) > 0$ could mean both eigenvalues are negative.

Comment: positive definiteness implies all evalues are positive, so det is $\textbf{strictly positive}$. Here positive det implies two negative evalues also. Then look at the trace which is sum of evalues too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove a matrix is positive definite by checking if the determinant of all of its leading minors are greater then 0.
$$\begin{vmatrix} a\end{vmatrix}>0 \iff a>0 \space\space\space(1)$$

$$\begin{vmatrix} 
a & 2 \\
2 & a+1
\end{vmatrix} = a^2+a-4$$
$$a^2+a-4>0 \iff a>\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2} \space\space\space OR \space\space\space\space a<\frac{-1-\sqrt{17}}{2}\space\space\space\space\space(2)$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can get that A is positive definite for any $a>\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$

Comment: Thanks a lot,now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

The last step is to note that since $a^2+a-4=(a-(-1+\sqrt{17})/2)(a-(-1-\sqrt{17})/2)$, we have that it is positive precisely on $(-\infty,(-1-\sqrt{17})/2)\cup((-1+\sqrt{17})/2,\infty)$.